# Plotting ECDF results in horizontal lines beyond the expected range. How can I prevent this?

Tags: r

I want to plot the ECDF of a vector. The vector has range [0,1]. However, plotting ECDF(data) results in horizontal lines that extend beyond this range. I want to create a plot that does not have these lines beyond the range [0,1].

Calling `plot.stepfun` shows that the function chooses a vector of abscissa values that includes the values -0.16 and 1.16, but I don't know why. I have tried manually selecting the abscissa values using the argument `xval`, but this made no difference.

I have tried using ggplot2, but again this made no difference.

I have also tried removing the first and last values of the vector, which are 0 and 1, but again this made no difference.

I could of course just use MS Paint, but that seems like a poor solution to the problem.

```
data <- c(0, 0.0267937939860966, 0.0831161599875003, 0.089312646620322, 
0.09, 0.162046969424378, 0.214535013990776, 0.216, 0.254227922418882, 
0.29770882206774, 0.3, 0.346218858110426, 0.3483, 0.351120057363453, 
0.446176768935429, 0.469316812739393, 0.47178, 0.506720537855168, 
0.51, 0.53499413030498, 0.577201705567453, 0.579825, 0.61501969832776, 
0.653481161056275, 0.657, 0.667975762603373, 0.6705828, 0.685122481157394, 
0.742234640167266, 0.74470167, 0.745169566125031, 0.756545373540315, 
0.7599, 0.795669365154443, 0.801746023714245, 0.803996766,     0.828933122166261, 
0.83193, 0.837497330035643, 0.848695641093207, 0.8506916541, 
0.87169919974533, 0.879781895687186, 0.882351, 0.885279431049518, 
0.8870099004, 0.899358675688768, 0.913502229556406, 0.914974950051, 
0.915505354483016, 0.9176457, 0.921514704291551, 0.935095914758442, 
0.9363300788754, 0.939114814765667, 0.940605918657197, 0.94235199, 
0.951503562401266, 0.95252438490057, 0.952993345228527,     0.958244748310785, 
0.959646393, 0.963897452890123, 0.964732400211852, 0.970641607614244, 
0.9717524751, 0.973212104364713, 0.973888411695313, 0.979355426072477, 
0.980181739205269, 0.98022673257, 0.980724900269631, 0.985376582975203, 
0.985481180229861, 0.98580953864678, 0.986158712799, 0.989235347816543, 
0.989578152973373, 0.989788073567854, 0.9903110989593, 0.9923627402258, 
0.992816530697457, 0.99321776927151, 0.994414541359167,     0.994946291138756, 
0.995252438490057, 0.995922615192192, 0.9964442204999, 0.99667670694304, 
0.997028536003077, 0.997497885105047, 0.997673694860128,     0.997837868960133, 
0.998239132446338, 0.998371586402089, 0.998429033902679, 0.998860091673285, 
0.998860110481463, 0.999173901730287, 0.999202077337024, 0.999402017502492, 
0.999441454135917, 0.999567612655648, 0.999609017895142, 0.999687669141686, 
0.999726312526599, 0.999774606597093, 0.999808418768619, 0.999837491356504, 
0.999865893138033, 0.99988293066653, 0.999906125196623, 0.999915732168455, 
0.999934287637636, 0.999939389009237, 0.999954001346345, 0.999956435850389, 
0.999967800942442, 0.999968709576019, 0.999977460659709, 0.999984222461796, 
0.999988955723257, 0.99999226900628, 0.999994588304396, 0.999996211813077, 
0.999997348269154, 1)

plot(ecdf(data), do.points=FALSE)
```

I would like to be able to plot the ECDF with the x axis matching the range of the vector, that is, [0,1].

Comment: Can't you do `plot(ecdf(data), do.points=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1))` ?

Comment: For even less of the axis, `plot(ecdf(data), do.points = FALSE, xlim = c(0,0.9616))`.

Comment: With `ggplot2` you can do `ggplot(df, aes(height)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point", pad=FALSE) `, with `df = data.frame(height = data)`.